# twitter-bootstrap-rails Uncaught TypeError / $ is not a function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems

While developing a rails app, I was in the google chrome inspect element console testing an ajax link when all of the sudden I noticed 12 errors of the same kind:

[image: Console log errors]

I have no clue what is happening here, but my app works just fine regardless. However, When I pull my app up in firefox, my app does not even load. I get stopped and this error pops up:

[image: Debug screen showing the error location]

I dont even know what else to say here because I am completely stumped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I found what was the problem was. When trying to get the bootstrap dropdown buttons to work the other day, I have rearranged the application.js folder to load bootstrap before jquery. I changed this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

to this:

```
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

At the time, this fixed the bootstrap dropdown problem. However, I now I realize that when bootstrap calls jquery, it will not have been loaded yet. Thus, the error `$ function does not exist`. Just changed the lines back to the proper order and all is now well.

Comment: So is your bootstrap dropdown problem now fixed? Because this is exactly the problem I'm having right now